# Cannot get script tags with curl for some pages?

Tags: javascript, php, curl

I'm trying to curl some of the users of livecoding.tv to get all page information.

However when i curl for example for this users 
https://www.livecoding.tv/locuester/

in the page scripts tags were not loaded.

https://www.livecoding.tv/camwhite/

if i curl this page, all page contents are properly loaded.

```
 $base = 'https://www.livecoding.tv/camwhite';

 $curl = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $base);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $base);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 $str = curl_exec($curl);
 curl_close($curl);

 echo $str
```

My aim is getting whole page of users inside of the script tags,i parse their rtmp link. Some of the users my whole code works fine, however many of the users my code had a problem because of response of curl.

What can be the problem about my curl result. Javascript cannot be loaded for some of the users.

Comment: cURL doesn't get content that is loaded dynamically !

Comment: These page structures are same, why it is working for some of the users ? and also i just want to take javascript code of page. nothing else.

Comment: When I run your code I see the RTMP links in the script tags for both users.  What exactly are you looking for that isn't found on the one page?

Comment: Now it works for both users. There are many users online in here. https://www.livecoding.tv/livestreams/ sometimes it works for specific users sometimes not. Now many users online if you try https://www.livecoding.tv/CMIZONY or https://www.livecoding.tv/LEARNTOPROGRAM it does not work.

Comment: I think they're blocking access if you aren't logged in after multiple requests.  When I hit that page, the stream doesn't load automatically and when I click play I get a popup saying "Sign up now to watch more livestreams, videos and chat with people" and it won't let me stream the video.

Comment: I'd suggest creating a free account, logging in with cURL and then fetching the streams.  It will probably give you the rtmp links each time once logged in.

Comment: Even if first time you run that script with people who we cannot get their information, we get same error. There should be another problem i think. However i ll try with logging in with curl before the each request.

Comment: I'm not sure how they decide whether or not to do that but if it's going by IP address - it would make sense that the first time you run the code it doesn't work since they're tracking access.  Or maybe its somewhat random if you aren't logged in.  In any case, logging in first may help make it more reliable.

Comment: Ty for helping @drew010. Logging solved my problem.

Comment: Glad that was it.  Good luck!